# How to set space between TextBox values into array

Tags: c#, windows

How to set space between TextBox values into array?

TextBox values:

> 1 32 54 76 89 89 454 23

Expected output array:

```
value[1]=1; 
value[2]=32; 
value[3]=76 
...
```

Comment: So... what is your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
var numbers = textBox1.Text.Split(' ');
List<int> lst = numbers.Select(item => int.Parse(item)).ToList();
```

It will be even better if you use method group like this:

```
List<int> lst = numbers.Select(int.Parse).ToList();
```

Then you can get it's values like this:

```
lst[0] --> 1
lst[1] --> 32
and ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You first have to split the users input:

```
var values = myTextBox.Text.Split(' ');
```

Now you can easily set your array of integers:

```
var myArr = values.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray();
```

Alternativly you can also use `Int.Parse` instead of `Convert.ToInt32`.

Comment: int myArr[] =Convert.ToInt32( values.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x)).ToArray());

Comment: Test it, but I guess not. The returned value arlay IS an array of ints

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] values = tv.Text.Split(' '); // the values as string

int[] arr = new int[values.Length];   // the values as integer
for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    arr[i] = int.Parse(values[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correct you need to create `int` array from string you can do it like this:

```
string TextBoxText = "1 32 54 76 89 89 454 23";
var value = TextBoxText.Split(' ').Select(Int32.Parse).ToList();
```

Then you can use your array like this:

```
Console.WriteLine(value[1]);
Console.WriteLine(value[2]);
```

`TextBoxText` should be `Text` property of your TextBox component.

Comment: @JaparJarkinbek what do you mean? Just put it in console application